# NGINX to trust a list of specific client certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I'd like to accomplish that scenario below.

Ningx must accept:

```
client_certificate_1.pem
client_certificate_2.pem
client_certificate_3.pem
```

OR

Ningx must accept:

```
file_with_certs.pem (containing)
    client_certificate_1
    client_certificate_2
    client_certificate_3
```

the problem is that I did not understand if that is possible or not: it seems I can specify the CAs to be trusted but not the individual client certificates.

The client certificates are TLS Web Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2) certificates issued by a public CA and the NGINX works in HTTPS (so no problems on that side).

Any help is welcome, thanks.